# this.sibling is undefiend why is it happening

Tags: html, jquery

I've been sitting here and searching for multiple explenations of why it's not working but i cant figure it out. Why is it undefiend?

I want number 55 or 45 to be alerted depending on which I click, but it wont do it.

```
<div class="antal">
<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i><h2 class="bidbutton">55</h2>
<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>

<div class="antal">
<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i><h2 class="bidbutton">45</h2>
<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>

$(".fa-plus-circle").click(function(){
alert($(this).siblings('.bidbutton').innerHTML);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vhteLgmr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the jQuery object has no property called `innerHTML`.  The *HTML element* does:

```
alert($(this).siblings('.bidbutton')[0].innerHTML);
```

Or you can use the `.html()` function on the jQuery object:

```
alert($(this).siblings('.bidbutton').html());
```

Comment: Thanks, im pretty new so couldn't figure it out